# Add non connected vertices to igraph

Tags: r, igraph

I have an edge list eg: df:

```
sample1    sample2
sample2    sample3
sample1    sample3
```

I have an additional 2 samples, sample4 and sample5 which have no connections to any other vertices.

A full list of samples is held in a separate data frame eg df2:

```
sample1
sample2
sample3
sample4
sample5
```

How can I add these non-connected edges so that the show in my igraph (and so that the are included in the network analysis?)

Comment: Please use `dput()` to show your data!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually very easy. You can use the function `graph_from_data_frame` to build your network, as I assume you know.

As `vertices` parameter you can include all the relevant nodes you need (eg. sample1 ... to sample5), and as `d` parameter (referred to de edges) the list of edges where in one column (named `from`) you set the origin vertice, and in the other (named `to`) the vertice of destination.

Example of "vertices" (I call it "nodes" below) dataframe

```
id
sample1
sample2
sample3
```

Example of "edge" dataframe

```
from to
sample1 sample2
```

You can use then:

```
require("igraph")
net = graph_from_data_frame(d=edge, vertices=nodes, directed=FALSE)
plot ( net )
```

For instance. As you can see in the example, the vertex 1 and 2 are connected, while the 3 stands alone.

Please let me recommend you this tutorial: http://kateto.net/networks-r-igraph